# Assign a member function pointer as a callback from another function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class A that has a function pointer for a callback. The default values are some function pointer from class A but I want to assign a function pointer  from class B. I tried `std::function` and `std::bind` but it is not working. I tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791121/c-how-to-pass-member-function-pointer-to-another-class) but without success.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class A{
public:
    typedef void(*action)() ;

    A( std::function<void()> a  = nullptr)
    {
        if(a)
            m_Func = a; 
        else
            m_Func = std::bind( (this->*(this->dummyFunction))() );
    }
    std::function<void(void)> m_Func;
    void dummyFunction(void){std::cout<<"dummy function\n" <<std::endl;}
};

class B{
public:
    std::function<void()> m_Bfunc(){ std::cout << "class B func\n" <<std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  A a(b.m_Bfunc);
  a.m_Func();
}
```

I want that the function `m_Bfunc` to run.

Comment: `action` is ultimately pointless in this code; get rid of it. Just saying, and it appears you want the `bind` to be (a) correct (which it isn't) and (b) done from `main` (which given this layout is the only sane place to wire up `b` with `B:m_BFunc`).

Comment: `std::function<void()> m_Bfunc(){ std::cout << "class B func\n" <<std::endl;}` declares a functions named `m_Bfunc` that returns a `std::function<void()>`, since the function does not return that you're into the realm of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want:

```
class A{
public:
    A(std::function<void()> a = nullptr)
    {
        if(a)
            m_Func = a; 
        else
            m_Func = [this](){ dummyFunction(); };
    }
    std::function<void()> m_Func;
    void dummyFunction(){std::cout<<"dummy function\n" <<std::endl;}
};

class B{
public:
    void func(){ std::cout << "class B func\n" <<std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  A a([&](){b.func(); });
  a.m_Func();
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/qPleUc)