# C++ Saving member function pointer to a class variable

Tags: c++, functional-programming, bind

I'm a newbie C++ programmer so this may get messy.

I am writing a program to convert a binary Windows ETL file to Wireshark PCAPNG.  To be more accurate, I'm fixing a bug that has arisen due to a change in the ETL format.  To fix the bug I need to add a callback to my code.  Here are the relevant sections from the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>

// Ng Block Buffer
typedef struct _NG_BLK_BUFFER {
    int blockType = 0;

    // ...
} NG_BLK_BUFFER;

class RingBuffer
{
public:
    // ...
    std::function<void(NG_BLK_BUFFER*)> framePayloadWriter;
};

class PcapNgFile : public std::ofstream
{
public:
    // ...
    PcapNgFile(const std::wstring fileName, size_t ringBufferSize);

    void writeEPB();
    // ...

    RingBuffer* ringBuffer;
};

PcapNgFile::PcapNgFile(const std::wstring fileName, size_t ringBufferSize)
{
    // ...
    this->ringBuffer = new RingBuffer();

    this->ringBuffer->framePayloadWriter = std::bind(&PcapNgFile::writeEPB, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}

void PcapNgFile::writeEPB()
{
    std::cout << "Writing an EPB" << std::endl;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv)
{
    PcapNgFile* myPcapNg = new PcapNgFile(L"test.pcap", 1);
}
```

For line 36, I get the error:

```
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__thiscall PcapNgFile::* )(void),PcapNgFile *,const std::_Ph<1> &>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Line 36 is:

```
this->ringBuffer->framePayloadWriter = std::bind(&PcapNgFile::writeEPB, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ii think its duplacte to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566943/assign-a-member-function-pointer-as-a-callback-from-another-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign a member function pointer as a callback from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566943/assign-a-member-function-pointer-as-a-callback-from-another-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeEPB` takes no parameters but you are trying to bind it to a function which does take parameters, change it to `writeEPB(NG_BLK_BUFFER*)`.

If you want to ignore the parameter in the callback remove the placeholder from your bind call:

```
this->ringBuffer->framePayloadWriter = std::bind(&PcapNgFile::writeEPB, this);
```

Using a lambda rather than `std::bind` may be slightly more efficient and tends to give better error messages. e.g.:

```
this->ringBuffer->framePayloadWriter = [this](){ writeEPB(); };
```

gives a more understandable error message, the correct lambda would be:

```
this->ringBuffer->framePayloadWriter = [this](NG_BLK_BUFFER*){ writeEPB(); };
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and concise answer Alan.